# Показать окно поверх других окон в полноэкранном-режиме

Tags: c#, framework

Я сделал чит меню для игры, но оно не работает если игра в полноэкранном-режиме.
Использую C# .Net Framework 4.8
Я пробовал WinApi, BrightToFont, TopMost,OpenGL Hook(не пробовал, но не подходит) - ничего не помогло.
Помню видел две похожие темы на других форумах, сейчас эти темы удалены(либо я не нашёл их по ключевым словам).

В первой теме было сказано что есть приложение на С#, делающие скриншоты, так вот её уведомления были не от винды, но всё же показывались а полноэкранном-режиме.

В второй же теме человек нашёл ответ, но тема была удалена.

Comment: Нативный полноэкранный режим - устаревшая технология, и пролезть туда может только DirectX Overlay. То есть если хотите там что-то рисовать, вам нужно использовать напрямую DirectX. Новыми играми такой режим не используется.

Comment: @aepot А какие ещё есть полноэкранные режимы?

Comment: Есть все остальные режимы похожи на окно размером во весь экран. Там не должно быть данной проблемы.